# fgets read file and store into a variable

Tags: php

I have Multiple URL in `result.txt` file. I want to use first URL with fgets.

Problem is that fgets not passing value to `file_get_html` for next process.

```
$file = fopen("result.txt","r");
$link = fgets($file);
// echo fgets($file);       // Here I get URL successfully 

$html = file_get_html($link);   // Problem, Not receiving URL

foreach($html->find('.singcont a') as $a) {
    $links = $a->href;
    echo $links;
}
```

How to pass `$link` value to `file_get_html` ?

> If I use this way it works `$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/');`

Comment: I guess the first line is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a newline or some other character at the end of the returned `$link` string.

```
var_dump($link);
```

It might output a string that looks like this:

```
string(19) "http://example.com
"
```

To remedy the issue you could either use **[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** or **[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)**:

> <sub>**trim** ( *string* **$str** [, *string* **$character_mask** = "
>   \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] ) : *string*</sub>

```
$link = trim($link);
```

> <sub>**substr** ( *string* **$string** , *int* **$start** [, *int*
>   **$length** ] ) : *string*</sub>

```
$link = substr($link, 0, -1);
```

↳ [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: You could use  `trim` too.

Answer (score -1):

You could put `$html = file_get_html($link);` in the for loop, so your code will be like:

```
$file = fopen("result.txt","r");
$link = fgets($file);
// echo fgets($file);       // Here I get URL successfully 

foreach($html->find('.singcont a') as $a) {
    $links = $a->href;
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    echo $links;
}
```

Comment: Should be wrong answer, because `$html` is not set.

Comment: @shingo $html is set in the foreach loop

Comment: But before it is set $html is used at the beginning of the foreach loop, the loop won't start and leave a fatal error.